# Is there any equivalent of chgrp -R in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-os

I want to change the group name of one directory recursively, I am using os.chown() to do that. But I can not find any recursive flag like (chgrp -R) in os.chown().

Comment: Correct. Recurse manually.

Comment: So I must os.walk and change every files group using os.chown() ?

Comment: @FujiClado Yes,

Comment: I wrote a function to perform chgrp -R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function to perform chgrp -R

```
def chgrp(LOCATION,OWNER,recursive=False):

  import os 
  import grp

  gid = grp.getgrnam(OWNER).gr_gid
  if recursive:
      if os.path.isdir(LOCATION):
        os.chown(LOCATION,-1,gid)
        for curDir,subDirs,subFiles in os.walk(LOCATION):
          for file in subFiles:
            absPath = os.path.join(curDir,file)
            os.chown(absPath,-1,gid)
          for subDir in subDirs:
            absPath = os.path.join(curDir,subDir)
            os.chown(absPath,-1,gid)
      else:
       os.chown(LOCATION,-1,gid)
  else:
    os.chown(LOCATION,-1,gid)
```

Comment: Why so complicated when one could just pass the chgpr -R to the shell?

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you just pass your command to the shell?

```
os.system("chgrp -R ...")
```

Comment: A reason not to do that are security concerns. Consider a filename that includes `$(rm -rf /)`. Also there are more trivial problems like filenames containing spaces and/or quote chars.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the solution by @fuji-komalan and doing a few things differently:

```
import os.
import shutil
from itertools import chain

def chgrp(path, group, recursive=False):
    def prepend_dirpath(dirpath):
        def f(fn):
            return os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
        return f
    shutil.chown(path, -1, group)
    if recursive:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for f in map(prepend_dirpath(dirpath), chain(dirnames, filenames)):
                shutil.chown(f, -1, group)
```

With using `shutil.chown` you don't need to explicitly lookup the gid of the group. (Though only doing it once has probably a slight performance advantage.)